# Create table with references to a composite primary key table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a composite primary key table:

```
class CreateWines < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :wines, primary_key: [:name, :producer_id] do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to create another table with a one-many relationship:

```
class CreateWineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :wine_items do |t|
      t.string :vintage
      t.references :wine, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

I recived the error in the db:migrate:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

I was playing with the references passing the columns and the primary_key of the table:

```
class CreateWineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :wine_items do |t|
      t.string :vintage
      t.references :wine, null: false, foreign_key: { column: [:name, :producer_id],
                                         primary_key: [:name, :producer_id]}
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I recevied a more specific error:

```
For composite primary keys, specify :column and :primary_key, where :column must
reference all the :primary_key columns from "wines"
```

What is the correct way to create a reference association with a table with a composite primary key?

Comment: The references method does not appear to support composite keys. You'll need to create the individual columns and then add a composite foreign key add_foreign_key :wine_items, :wines, primary_key: [:name, :producer_id]

Answer (score 0):

`references` doesn't support CPK (yet). You need to add the columns and then fkey manually, eg.:

```rb
create_table :wine_items do |t|
  t.string :vintage
  t.string :wine_name, null: false
  t.integer :wine_producer_id, null: false
  t.foreign_key :wines, column: %i[wine_name wine_producer_id], primary_key: %i[name producer_id]

  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Thanks @smathy, but I implemented your solution, I can create a new wine_item: WineItem.create!(vintage: "2010", wine_name: Wine.first.name, wine_producer_id: Wine.first.producer_id), but when I try to: WineItem.first.wine then: .rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/bundler/gems/rails-a967d355c6fe/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:563:in `check_validity!': Association WineItem#wine primary key ["name", "producer_id"] doesn't match with foreign key wine_id. Please specify query_constraints, or primary_key and foreign_key values. (ActiveRecord::CompositePrimaryKeyMismatchError)

Comment: need to add the query constraint to the association belongs_to :wine, query_constraints: [:name, producer_id]

Comment: Actually it needs to be `wine_name` and `wine_producer_id`, on the `has_many` too I believe.

Comment: thanks @smathy and debugger. To accessing in both sides (WineItem.first.wine, Wine.first.wine_items) I have to add the query constraint in both models like this: `has_many :wine_items, query_constraints: [:wine_name, :wine_producer_id]` and `belongs_to :wine, query_constraints: [:wine_name, :wine_producer_id]`, The wine 'prefix' in both.